# Background Color/Image drawn but shapes will not show up

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent

I am just simply trying to draw an object to my `JPanel` but it will not appear. The method that is being used to create the Rectangle that is representing the object is being called, but the object will not appear on screen.

This is my main class that sets up the `JFrame` and the `JPanel` and has the `paintComponent` method that is being used to draw everything.

This is my main class

```
public class BrickBreaker extends JPanel
{
private static int WIDTH = 600;
private static int HEIGHT = 400;
private Paddle paddle = new Paddle(WIDTH/2 - 25, HEIGHT - 25);

public BrickBreaker()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    Dimension size = new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    frame.setSize(size);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.addKeyListener(paddle);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    BrickBreaker game = new BrickBreaker();
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    paddle.draw(g);
}
```

I also have my `Paddle` class that is used to create a paddle object, and it has a `draw` method that I am using to try and just draw a basic Rectangle

```
public class Paddle
{

private int x, y;
private Rectangle paddle;

public Paddle(int x, int y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    paddle = new Rectangle(x, y, 50, 10);
}

public void draw(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    g.drawRect(paddle.x, paddle.y, 75, 10);
    g.fillRect(paddle.x, paddle.y, 75, 10);
}
}
```

I have done basic tests like changing the `paddle.x, paddle.y` to hard-coded coordinates, but the Rectangle will not show up

I have also added a `BufferedImage` to the `paintComponent` method in my main class, and that gets drawn to the screen. I have also added checks to make sure the `draw` method is being called, and it is.

I am assuming I setup the `JPanel` incorrectly, but I am not too sure what I did wrong.

Comment: This `frame.setVisible(true);` needs to be called *last*, after adding all components. Otherwise, you're just setting a blank JFrame visible and nothing more.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I will change that to avoid any potential problems, but this didn't solve my problem. Thanks for the response

Comment: Your paddle is also being drawn **off** the screen. Change your paddle coordinates so that they are within the confines of the JPanel.

Comment: It's being drawn at [275, 375] which is smaller than the size of the JPanel (you're setting the size of the JFrame, including its menu bar). Restrict the size of the JPanel via its `preferredSize` and then pack the JFrame.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ah, thanks. Didn't realize I was not setting the size of the JPanel. Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't ever be setting sizes anyway. Better to set preferred size and then to pack the JFrame. Better still to override `public Dimension getPreferredSize()` and return a value that makes sense.